# How extract all values for one set of key

Tags: python, dictionary

How extract all values from one set of key, without write all keys, for the a dictionary with two (or more) entries, not use loop, for example:

```
dictionary={'a':{'a1':'1','a2':'2','a3':'3'},'b':{'a1':'x','a2':'y','a3':'z'}}

dictionary[*]['a1']
```

I will can return '1' & 'x'

Comment: What do you mean by "without write all keys?"

Comment: Well, you could do `map(operator.itemgetter('a1'), dictionary.itervalues())` - which doesn't use an explicit loop, but not sure why you're trying to avoid a loop anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import operator

dictionary={'a':{'a1':'1','a2':'2','a3':'3'},'b':{'a1':'x','a2':'y','a3':'z'}}

map(operator.itemgetter('a1'), dictionary.itervalues())

OUTPUT:
['1', 'x']
```

In case if you want multiple items

```
result = map(operator.itemgetter('a1', 'a2'), dictionary.itervalues())
zip(*result)

OUTPUT:
[('1', 'x'), ('2', 'y')]
```

If you wanted as dictionary

```
keys = ['a1', 'a2']
values = map(operator.itemgetter(*keys), dictionary.itervalues())
dict(zip(keys, zip(*values)))

OUTPUT:
{'a1': ('1', 'x'), 'a2': ('2', 'y')}
```

Comment: is the answer match with the question?

Comment: I guess ... any suggestions/improvements you see ?

Comment: @Aedil I think more the point is that `[('1', 'x')]` is just `['1', 'x']` - not quite sure how you managed to paste a one-item list with a tuple with the code (that does look fairly similar to my comment :))

Comment: @JonClements ... that was mistake, updated output, and yeah just saw your comment, thats exactly the same :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks updated answer. Answers was my assumptions instead of exact output from console :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for a list comprehension.

```
dictionary={'a':{'a1':'1','a2':'2','a3':'3'},'b':{'a1':'x','a2':'y','a3':'z'}}

output = [dictionary[x]['a1'] for x in dictionary]
print output
```

Output:

```
['1', 'x']
```

---

If there is concern that the subkey `a1` does not exist for all values, then we should probably switch to `dict.get`, which will return `None` for all those cases where `a1` is not in the dictionary.

```
output = [dictionary[x].get('a1') for x in dictionary]
```

Alternately, if we do not want a filler `None` value, we can do as JohnClements suggested and use a filter.

```
output = [dictionary[x]['a1'] for x in dictionary if 'a1' in dictionary[x]]
```

Comment: probably better to use `dict.get`.

Comment: If `None`s (or other default value aren't required) then perhaps even `[dictionary[x]['a1'] for x in dictionary if 'a1' in dictionary[x]]`

Comment: @JonClements, what is more efficient using yours above or  `[x.get("a1") for x in dictionary.itervalues() if x.get("a1")]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's more efficient and flexible to check for the existence of the key in the dict than it is to retrieve the value of the key twice. Especially where `None` is a valid value in which case you'd have to use sentinel objects with `get` to filter them out in the list-comp.

Comment: @JonClements,  if you use `if x.get("a1")` there won't be any None values though, how does an `in` check compare with a `dict.get`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `dict.get` underneath the hood effectively does `if key in dict: return dict[key]; return default_value` - since you don't need the value - you've got an immediately discarded value being returned. It will also fail where a false-like (but otherwise valid value (`None`/`False`/`''` for instance)) exists as the value for the key. eg: If `dictionary['a']['a1']` was `0`, then it'd be filtered out using your approach - although it looks very much like a valid value

Comment: @Jon Clements so basically anything that evaluates to False that is stored as a value  will get discarded

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes... the way around it using `dict.get` is to create a unique sentinel object and provide that as the default value to be returned. `sentinel = object(); if dict.get('key', sentinel) is not sentinel` - Which is somewhat overkill for simple membership testing...

Comment: @merlin2011 +1 sorry for hijacking your answer comments.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, No worries. I assume that between the answer above and the comments below, the OP will find something he can use. :P